# Tortoise SVN didn't show new files, now doesn't show it's context menu

Tags: upgrade, tortoise-svn

I was using tortoisesvn (maybe 1.6.7) and all of the sudden I noticed that new files weren't being displayed by either the commit command or the "check for modifications" command.  So I upgraded to 1.6.10 and rebooted and now there is nothing in my context menu.  The icon overlays are also gone, but that's not quite as big of a deal as completely missing the svn from the context menu.  Any ideas? Thanks...

update:  I uninstalled/reinstalled and my context menu is back.  However, it's still not showing new files.

Comment: Did you explicitly add the new files first to make sure they are tracked?

Comment: no - I've never had to do that in the past.  Tortoise would list them as unknown or whatever.  similar to this 

$ svn status
?       mst.vim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a bunch of checkboxes in the bottom left of these screens one of which is
"Show unversioned files"

Check that and it'll work as you expected.

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem with the last version. All context menus related to SVN as well as the icons were gone. I had to reinstall the client and reboot the machine to get these icons and the context menu back, maybe this helps you as well.